# PHP links not working (nginx)

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress, links, phpbb

I am trying to install phpBB on my Pi.
This is the base site of the installation:

```
192.168.178.62/phpBB3/install/app.php
```

this is the url which it trys to go to:

```
http://192.168.178.62/phpBB3/install/app.php/install
```

Which returns an 404. This is happening with all inside links, like support or license.
My nginx config:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html info.php;

        server_name 192.168.178.62;

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /pad/ {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.178.62:9001/;
        }

        location /chat {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.178.62:3002/;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }
```

The file fastcgi-php.conf is in /etc/nginx/snippets and its content is this:
    # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(/.*)$;

```
# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Comment: What is in the file `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf`?

Comment: Just copied that code from some tutorial. I will look at it in ca. 7 hours

Comment: @RichardSmith edited

Comment: You should add a newline before the code block, so that the question is formatted correctly.

Comment: Try changing `location ~ \.php$` to `location ~ \.php($|/)`